# Get high remainder after division in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, division

7/2 = 3.5

How do I get high number of the remainder? In this example it should be 4, not 3.

Comment: I don't think 'remainder' is the right term for what you seem to be asking: see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the Math.ceil function:

```
Math.ceil(7/2);  #4
```

The ceil is short for ceiling which will always round up, so anything >3 would become 4.

The opposite of this is Math.floor, which will always round down, so anything <4 will become 3.

Comment: +1 It also works for negative values, because `Math.ceil(-7/2)` will result in `-3`, not `-4` (which is lower than `-3`), as the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Math.ceil()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) for positive numbers, or [`Math.floor()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp) for negative ones.

Comment: it depends what the OP wants, `Math.ceil(-1.5)` will give you `-1` and `Math.floor(-1.5)` will give you `-2` - the first one still gives you the _higher_ number (because `-1 > -2`).

Comment: Yeah, I certainly know how they work; I've made an assumption about what the original poster wants, that he doesn't want to truncate the fractional parts.

Answer (score 0):

The remainder in 7/2 is 1. I don't think you meant to ask about remainders.

Is your question really 'How do I round a decimal number to the nearest integer?' - in which case 3.5 should round up to 4, but 3.4 should round down to 3? If so, you want the `Math.round()` function:

```
Math.round(7/2) //returns 4 (3.5 rounded up).
Math.round(3.5) //returns 4 (3.5 rounded up).
Math.round(3.4) //returns 3 (3.4 rounded down).
Math.round(10/3) //returns 3 (3.33333333 rounded down).
```